# About jQuery .ready() function

Tags: jquery, dom

In terms of execution time and resources employed, is it more convenient to load as much stuff as possible with `jQuery.ready()` or the bare essentials?

Comment: don't use it at all, but your JS ob the bottom of your page. But you should use it only to initialize what you want to do. Not to put all your code in it.

Comment: If you mean bare essentials as `document.ready`, you should replace that. Otherwise I didn't edit that part as I wasn't too sure what you meant by "bare essentials" ;)

Comment: @shaz: "bare essentials"==minimum stuff to load with it, strictly necessary :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use it as trigger for you init functions... Don't put all your code in it:

don't do:

```
$(function(){
  var someFunction = function(){
   $("a").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
   });
  };
  someFunction();
});
```

do:

```
var someFunction = function(){
   $("a").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
   });
};
$(function(){
  someFunction();
});
```

its more readable, and it simply makes no sense to put all your code in the ready function.

ps:

`$(function(){})` === 
`$(document).ready()`

Comment: So, for example it's more convenient to use onClick attribute to call a function when we need instead of use .click() included in .ready()...right?

Comment: not exactly. The document ready is hare to make sure that the DOM has been interpreted by the browser. So in the case of you click, it just makes sure the browser knows of the element you want to bind your click on.

Comment: Ok, but...It's better to use onClick event in html tag and call a function when we need or preload this function in $(document).ready() and using .click()?

Comment: not its not better at all... use .click() i updated my example